# gnu make: check if a file is a directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a variable `$(target)`

I am constructing a variable `$(target_dir)`

The conditions for this are:

- if `target` is a local directory, then `target_dir` is **`curr_dir/target`**
- if `target` is **not** a local directory, then `target_dir` is **`curr_dir`**

Currently I am using `$(wildcard ...)` to check if `curr_dir/target` exists:

```
target_as_dir := $(shell pwd)/$(target)
target_is_dir := $(if $(wildcard $(target_as_dir)),1,)
target_dir    := $(if $(target_is_dir),$(target_as_dir),$(shell pwd))
```

However, this falls down in the following scenario

```
src/
+--- foo/
     +-- makefile
     +-- foo.cc
     +-- foo -> ../build/foo/foo (this is a symlink)
```

I am in `src/foo`, and `$(target) = foo`

My `$(wildcard)` statement above **matches the `foo` symlink**, which I don't want it to do.

I need it to match **only if it's a directory**. Any other filesystem type should not match.

- How can I find if `curr_dir/target` is a directory, and not some other file?

Comment: Do you mean, `foo` is a symlink to a directory but you don't want it to match even then?  Or is it OK if `foo` is a symlink to a directory but not if `foo` is a symlink to a file?

Comment: No, the `foo` symlink will only ever be a symlink to a file. I've realised this can be solved as easily as adding `./` on the end of `target_as_dir` in the wildcard check: ie: `$(if $(wildcard $(target_as_dir)/.),1,)`

Comment: Correct.  That's why I was wondering, because if you need to know if it's a symlink per se, not what the symlink points to, that's much harder.  Very few UNIX tools actually let you see the type of the symlink itself, they almost all follow the symlink by default and show you the thing it points to.  If your system has `stat` (most do) that's your best bet.  But you'll have to use `$(shell ...)` to use it; make itself can't ever tell the difference between a symlink and what it points to.

Answer (score 3):

You could use unix `test` command.

```
target = foo
target_as_dir := $(shell pwd)/$(target)
target_is_dir := $(shell test -d $(target_as_dir) -a ! -h $(target_as_dir); echo $$?)
target_dir    := $(if  $(and $(findstring 0,$(target_is_dir)),$(findstring $(target_is_dir),0)),$(target_as_dir),$(shell pwd))

all:
    echo $(target_dir)
```

`test -d $(target_as_dir) -a ! -h $(target_as_dir)` checks if it is a directory (-d) and (-a) not (!) a symlink (-h). The result is either 0 or 1. 0 is for a directory, and 1 is for everything else.

The `$(and $(findstring....` part is just a comparison of two strings. Unfortunatelly I don't know a better way to compare two strings in a Makefile without using 3rd party libraries.